# How do i handle error from an api call in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building an application that keep track of the books i'm currently reading, the ones i have read and the ones i want to read. I used and API to SEARCH for books and add to the app. The problem is from the search. After searching for something the below error occurs when all of the text is deleted out of the search input box.

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:832:20
  829 | _BooksAPI__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__["search"](query.trim(), 20).then(function (result) {
  830 |   var noneResult = false;
  831 | 
> 832 |   if (result.error) {
      |              ^  833 |     noneResult = true;
  834 |     result = [];
  835 |   }
```

```
class SearchPage extends Component{
  
  state = {
    query:'',
    booksAnswer: [],
    noneResult: false
  }
  
  search(event){
    const query = event.target.value;
    if(query.length===0)
        this.setState({
            booksAnswer: [],
            noneResult: false
        })
        
    BooksAPI.search(query.trim(), 20).then((result)=>{
        let noneResult = false;
        if(result.error){
            noneResult = true;
            result = [];
            }

let promises = [];
result.forEach((elem, key)=>{
    promises.push(
        BooksAPI.get(elem.id).then((data)=>{
            result[key]["shelf"] = data.shelf 
        })
    );
})
Promise.all(promises).then(()=>{
        this.setState({
            booksAnswer: result,
            noneResult: noneResult
        })
});
    })
  }
  
    render (){
        return (
            <div className="search-books">
            <div className="search-books-bar">
              <Link className="close-search" to="/">Close</Link>
              <div className="search-books-input-wrapper">
          
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search by title or 
               author" onChange={(event)=>this.search(event)}/>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="search-books-results">
              <ol className={"books-grid "+(this.state.noneResult ? "hideResult": "")}>
                      {this.state.booksAnswer.map((value)=>(
                        <li key={value.id}>
                            <Book manageBookShelf={this.props.manageBookShelf} bookData={value} />
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ol>
                <p className={(!this.state.noneResult ? "hideResult": "")}>No results</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
export default SearchPage;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `catch` to handle when fetch API error

```
BooksAPI.search(query.trim(), 20)
  .then((result) => {
    let noneResult = false;
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    noneResult = true;
    result = [];
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. This did solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
BooksAPI.search(query.trim(), 20).then((result)=>{
    if(!result)return;// <-   
    ...
});
```